# C++ STL transform

Tags: string, dictionary, vector, int

I try to use c++ stl library. 
I'd like to transform a vector of string to a map of int, string.

For example: a vector that looks like that:

```
const char *vinit[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" };
vector <string> v(vinit, end(vinit));
```

Will transform to a map like that:

```
    map<int, string> map = {{ 1, "Sunday" },
                            { 2, "Monday" },
                            { 3, "Tuesday" },
                            { 4, "Wednesday" } };
```

The point is that I can't use any loops and a global index as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
you can use `map::insert` for this:

```
const char *vinit[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" };
vector <string> v(vinit, end(vinit));
std::map<int,string> map;
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    map.insert (std::pair<int,string>(i+1,v[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'd like to know, it just an example..
I'd like to do it on run time, not hard-coded.

Comment: Can't use loops, do you have another solution?

Comment: Why you can't use loops? 
If you want to avoid loops, the solution is to make it explicits like:

`int i = 0; map.insert(std::pair<int,string>(i+1, v[i])); i++; if(i<v.size()){ //continue} else {//break}`

Comment: There is no ant stl algorithm such as transform that might help here?

Comment: Can you declare a second vector? Or declare a vector of std::pair?

Comment: If you can do this, you can declare a `std::vector<std::pair<int,string>>` and create a vector of int, where you can store the value for the map, and then
`std::map<std::string, int> mapped_values;

std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), 
          std::inserter(mapped_values, mapped_values.begin()));`